# What does `exposing (..)` mean in Elm?

Tags: elm

I'm trying to understand [the very first Elm example](http://elm-lang.org/edit/examples/Elements/HelloWorld.elm) and it has this:

`import Graphics.Element exposing (..)`

What does `exposing (..)` mean?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`exposing (..)` allows you to call all the functions in the package directly.

For example, if SamplePackage had the functions x and y, 
`import SamplePackage` would let you call `SamplePackage.x` and `SamplePackage.y`, while
`import SamplePackage exposing (..)` would let you call `x` and `y` without specifying their containing package.

Note that `import SamplePackage exposing (x)` would let you call `x` directly, but you would still need to call y with `SamplePackage.y`. Likewise, `import SamplePackage exposing (x, y)` would let you call `x` and `y`, but not any other functions in the package.

Comment: What would happen if you imported two packages with this syntax and they both had methods 'X'?

Answer (score 8):

It means that you can access everything directly within the Graphics.Element module, without specifying the package first.  Since this example only uses "show" and "Element", you could change the import line to:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (Element, show)
```

And it will still work for this example.

Comment: I think your answer is better than the accepted one, because you pointed out the difference between `exposing (..)` and `exposing (Element, show)`.

Comment: I'd suggest also adding that if only `import Graphics.Elements` was used, you can still access everything (that is public) in the `Graphics.Element` module like this: `Graphics.Element.Element` and `Graphics.Element.show`

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but I'll answer anyway with another way to think of `exposing (..)`, and explain a little about why it's usually a bad idea. If you have a background in Python programming, then you can think of this as like `from module import *` in Python. This Elm code:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (Element, show)
```

would look like this in Python:

```
from Graphics.Element import Element, show
```

whereas this Elm code:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)
```

would look like this in Python:

```
from Graphics.Element import *
```

The first two will **only** add the names `Element` and `show` to your current module's namespace; the latter two examples will add **all** the names from `Graphics.Element` to your namespace. This is convenient when you're first writing your module, as you might not know yet what names you're going to need from `Graphics.Element`. But once you've finished writing your module, it's wise to go back and change `exposing (..)` to `exposing (just, the, names, you, need)`. That way you can be sure of not having any name collisions later.

For an example of how name collisions could be bad, say you write a module called `myGraphics`, in which you create a function called `rotatedImage`, because it's not (currently) in `Graphics.Element`. But later on, `Graphics.Element` adds a `rotatedImage` function, with subtly different semantics (e.g., your function used degrees, but the "official" function used radians). Now there are *two* `rotatedImage` functions that your code has available... and you could easily trip yourself up:

```
{- someOtherModule.elm -}
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)

{- ... more code ... -}
someImage = rotatedImage (pi / 2) sourceImage  -- Angle is in radians
```

Now you need a different function from your `myGraphics` module, so you import it:

```
{- someOtherModule.elm -}
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)
import myGraphics exposing (..)

{- ... more code ... -}
someImage = rotatedImage (pi / 2) sourceImage  -- WHOOPS, angle is now in degrees!
```

And suddenly the rotation of `someImage` has changed! When you imported `myGraphics`, did you intend for it to change how `someImage` looked on your page? Almost certainly not.

**That's** why `import Foo exposing (..)` should be avoided once your code is relatively stable. It's very useful in development, since you don't have to constantly be going back to the top of your code to add another name to your `import` statement. But once you've finished doing heavy development on your module and you're only making occasional changes to it, you should really switch to using `import Foo exposing (just, the, names, you, need)`. You'll dodge many traps that way.